# What does log likelihood in dfittool in Matlab means?

Tags: statistics, matlab

I have a data set (400 real valued numbers between zero and one) which I need to fit an appropriate distribution to this data set. I used "dfittool" of Matlab and tried different distribution. For each distribution "dfittool" gives me a "log likelihood" of that distribution. My question is what does this value means? Does it mean the distribution with the highest log likelihood fits better to the data? Here is a summary of results:

```
Distribution ---- Log Likelihood

Normal_fit ----  1.8272

Exponential_fit  ----  24.3249

Logistic_fit  ----  -1.8729

Generalized Extreme Value_fit  ----   6.95018

Beta_fit  ----  62.81

Gamma_fit  ----  42.1661
```

I appreciate any help.

-Eli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the higher value of log likelihood indicate better fit. 
See the Wikipedia article [Maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) or these [lecture notes on MLE](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2003/lecture-notes/).

In a nutshell: having observed the values $x_1,\dots,x_n$ you want to choose the parameters of your distribution that maximize the product $\prod_k P(X_k=x_k)$. But this product is maximal when its logarithm is maximal, and the logarithm is easier to work with, because it's a sum.

The above applies to a discrete distribution. For a continuous distribution, one multiplies the values of probability density function, not the actual probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The distribution fitting here is an estimation problem. Also you could do this using 'mle' function of MATLAB which is a Maximum Likelihood Estimation.

So each distribution estimation which yields higher log likelihood has less estimation error in Maximum likelihood sense.